# New User Running a script with qsub

Tags: shell, command-line

I apologize beforehand, I am a new user so very detailed breakdowns are very welcome. I have copied a script I need to run my another persons directory. I need to run this using qsub. I attempted the obvious "qsub *script*"
The error "file must be an ascii script" appeared. A quick google search has told me that a shell script is necessary, but I do not know what that means, nor do I know how to write one.
It may be of interest that I was also told to copy a file called qsub.*example* as well, which I feel is probably relevant.

Once again, I apologize for my lack of experience here, I was not given much help or direction to work with here. I would just like to run this script.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so make a file, and let's call it run.sh. A shell script is just like a bat file on Windows, designed to be run on a command line interpreter. We'll use the Bash shell for this.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Signifies that this file uses the Bash interpreter. /bin/bash refers to the interpreter's absolute path on the filesystem.

So, according to https://www0.sun.ac.za/hpc/index.php?title=HOWTO_submit_jobs, I imagine you'd want something like this written into run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
./script
```

And then to run with qsub:

```
qsub run.sh
```

$PBS_O_WORKDIR is an environmental variable that refers to the absolute path of the current working directory where you called the qsub command.

The error you were getting, "file must be an ascii script", just means that qsub wants a shell script for its argument instead of your example file.